# How to convert vectors of pixels to a numpy array of an image

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, python-imaging-library

For example, the background-Mnist that I loaded from a mat file gives 50,000x784 for the training set.

There should be 50,000 of 28x28 image

I reshaped the whole thing using

```
    f_train = scio.loadmat('mnist_background_images/mnist_background_images_train.mat')
    f_test = scio.loadmat('mnist_background_images/mnist_background_images_test.mat')
    data_train = f_train['mnist_background_images_train']
    data_test = f_test['mnist_background_images_test'] #this gives 50,000x785 where last column is y
    x_train = data_train[:, :-1]
    x_test= data_test[:, :-1] #now it's 50,000x784
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, newshape=(-1, 28, 28 )) #new shape 50,000x28x28
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, newshape=(-1, 28, 28))
```

which gives out the correct dimension.

However, when I tried to show each image by

```
img = x_train[2]
out = Image.fromarray(img, mode = 'L')
```

```
print(x_train.shape)
```

gives (50000, 784)

The image came out looking nothing like an MNIST data at all. The pixels were mixed up and all over the place like everything was scrambled. Did I make a stupid mistake somewhere?

Comment: Can you show the lines where you load the data from the .mat file? Specifically, did you use `scipy.io.loadmat` or something else?

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys yes I did.

`f_train = scio.loadmat('mnist_background_images/mnist_background_images_train.mat')`

This was the code

Comment: Could you please add that to the question and also the output of `print(x_train.shape)` before the reshape operation. The reason for asking is that .mat files saved as '-v7.3' (HDF5) store arrays in transposed form and anyway, matlab code may not save the images in the shape that you expect.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys sorry for the late response, I have added the whole block of code.

Comment: Does the print statement really output `(50,000, 784)` with two commas?

Comment: Could you post a few lines of Matlab code where the data is created and saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your Python code is correct. It looks like your .mat file is corrupt or at least doesn't contain what you think it should contain. (I have personally had endless headaches with Python/Matlab data exchange.) It's unlikely, but you could try

```
data_train = data_train.T.reshape(50000, 785)
```

just in case a reshape action in Matlab was done incorrectly.

If you load the [original data](https://sites.google.com/a/lisa.iro.umoccntreal.ca/public_static_twiki/variations-on-the-mnist-digits), it is provided as text files with filename suffix `.amat`.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('mnist_background_images_test.amat', dtype=np.float32) # ￼shape (50000, 785)
scale = 255 / data.max() 
data8 = np.array(data * scale, dtype=np.uint8) # 8-bit image data

y = data[:, -1].astype(int)
x = data8[:, :-1].reshape(-1, 28, 28)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')
plt.imshow(x[2], cmap='Greys')
plt.show()
```

[image: One image from the MNIST set]

Comment: Thank you very much! This works :) I got the dataset from a friend and apparently it came in a mat file. Really appreciate your help!